# C# Jagged arrays for loop implementation question

Tags: c#, for-loop, jagged-arrays

I can't find how to implement jagged array using for loop.  I have tried, however only the last smaller array becomes jagged arrays item.

```
string[][] allSheets = new string[size][];
```

This is how I declare. Below is how I get allSheets[number] element.

```
public string[] get_Sheets(int colNum)
{
    CellReference[] cr = new CellReference[rows_.Length];
    ISheet sheet = wb.GetSheetAt(0);
    IRow[] row = new IRow[rows_.Length];
    ICell[] cell = new ICell[rows_.Length];
    string[] cellResult = new string[rows_.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < cr.Length; i++)
    {
        cr[i] = new CellReference(rows_[i] + colNum);
        row[i] = sheet.GetRow(cr[i].Row);
        cell[i] = row[i].GetCell(cr[i].Col);
        cellResult[i] = cell[i].ToString();
    }
    return cellResult;
}
```

My two for loops looks something like this:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++)
{
    for (int jj = 2; jj < size; jj++)
    {
        allSheets[ii] = get_Sheets(jj);

    }
}
```

Notice how I started `jj` with 2. I had to since it's how excel files work..
You could clearly see that despite everything my every `allSheets[ii]` would become the last possible j number in for loop.  I had tried to swap the loops so `i` starts first, however result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use only one loop, because you are iterating only the main array here. You do not have to handle 2 dimensions on this level. The second loop (for the other dimension) is already inside `get_Sheets`.

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++)
{
    allSheets[ii] = get_Sheets(ii + 2);
}
```

Note that your 2 for-loops are not executing in parallel, they are nested. The inner loop is iterating `size - 2` times per each iteration of the outer loop. This means that you are getting `size * (size - 2)` iterations. This not what you want.

An alternative way of doing this a lesser know feature of the for-loop. (This is probably what you intended to do with the 2 loops.)

```
for (int ii = 0, jj = 2; ii < size; ii++, jj++)
{
    allSheets[ii] = get_Sheets(jj);
}
```

Comment: It kinda works, however jj goes outside size and it shouldn't be bigger then size

Comment: Okay, but the range of indexes in `allSheets` and for `get_Sheets` must have the same size. Or does it make sense to have  `allSheets` bigger than the size of the worksheet? Maybe `size` should be smaller? Or if you want to leave empty space at the end of `allSheets`, then change the loop condition to `ii < size - 2`.